# Reasons for a C program to end all of a sudden while running (with no errors)

Tags: c, linked-list

I am doing a student record manager using a singly linked list. I made 9 functions.

1. For collecting data
2. For inserting at start
3. For inserting at end
4. For inserting after a given roll number
5. For deleting at start
6. For deleting at end
7. For deleting a student having a given roll number
8. for displaying the records
9. main function

Everything is working except 2(Though its working it doesn't give expected output).
When I do function 2 and then 8 this problem happens.

```
//Below is the 2nd function

void insert_after_rollno(void){
    int key,flag=0;
    struct student* ptr=start,*temp;
    printf("\nEnter the roll no to insert a student after that roll no :");
    scanf("%d",&key);
    while(ptr->next!=NULL){
        if(ptr->rollno==key){
            flag=1;
            ptr->next=temp;
            struct student* newnode;
            newnode=collect_data(newnode);
            ptr->next=newnode;
            newnode->next=temp;
            break;
        }
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
    if (ptr->next==NULL && ptr->rollno==key){
        flag=1;
        ptr->next=temp;
        struct student* newnode;
        newnode=collect_data(newnode);
        ptr->next=newnode;
        newnode->next=temp;
    }
    
    if (flag==0)
        printf("Invalid roll no");
}

//Below is the 8th function

void display(){//verified
    struct student* ptr=start;
    printf("\nRollno\tName\t\tMark1\tMark2");
    while(ptr!=NULL){
        printf("\n%d\t%s\t\t%.2f\t%.2f",ptr->rollno,ptr->name,ptr->marks[0],ptr->marks[1]);
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Review `struct student* newnode; newnode=collect_data(newnode);`  What value does the pointer `newnode` have when it is _passed to_ `collect_data()`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you still need help after fixing the issue identified in the previous comment please provide complete code as a [mre].

Comment: Be careful how you blame your tools. C has been used for literally _everything_ for over 50 years now, by untold gazillions of people. Your program crashed; clearly there is an error somewhere on your part. Good to ask why, but better to ask what you did wrong than blame the computer for not being smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting error is because you are initilly assigning ptr->next as temp instead of this logically you should store ptr->next to the temp .

Make
ptr->next=temp;
to  temp = ptr->next

```
if(ptr->rollno==key){
            flag=1;
            ptr->next=temp;  // Why are  you assigning temp here it should be temp = ptr->next
            struct student* newnode;
            newnode=collect_data(newnode);
            ptr->next=newnode;
            newnode->next=temp;  ///
            break;
        }
```